# Loading GADBannerView inside a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, admob

I am using AdMob and loading a GADBannerView into a UITableViewController instead of a general UIView. Can anyone tell me how to have the banner load in and just appear at the top of the table view? Below is the code:

In the nameViewController.h file:

```
@interface nameViewController : UITableViewController {
    GADBannerView *AbMob;
}
```

In the nameViewController.m file on (void)viewDidLoad:

```
//AdMob block
AbMob = [[GADBannerView alloc]
         initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                  self.view.frame.size.height -
                                  GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,
                                  GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                  GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];

AbMob.adUnitID = AdMob_ID;
AbMob.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:AbMob];

GADRequest *r = [[GADRequest alloc] init];
r.testing = YES;
[AbMob loadRequest:r];
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, right now its just kind of floating out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/google-mobile-dev/source/browse/AdCatalog/Classes/AdvancedLayoutUseCases/TableViewExample/TableViewExampleController.m?repo=adcatalog-ios) is a full-blown example of how to embed an ad at both the top and bottom of a table view. Slight modifications could be made to only show one at the top.

Note that per AdMob T&C, there can only be a maximum of 2 ads even in a long table view, and no more than 1 ad should be showing at one time. Just showing 1 ad at the top works just fine as well.

Comment: Is there really no recommended way to deal with this issue in an UITableViewController, like the OP asked? The example you linked to uses a UIViewController, but most simple table views use UITableViewController, so you don't need to hook up the table view, data source, and delegate yourself. Sure, I could go through the hassle of converting my UITableViewControllers into regular UIViewControllers, but I'd rather not, and I suspect I'm not alone in this.